# Adding a label to a plot in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to add a label on the right side of the plot I made. I searched up current solutions, but I can't incorporate them into my own plot.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis lines=middle, samples=50, grid, thick, domain=-2:2, ymin=-2, xmax=3]
\addplot[blue] {x^2} node[]{$x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I'd just like to add a blue label to the right side of that plot, saying `$y=x^2$`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

pgfplots calls these legends not labels, or you can add the text as a node:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [color=blue] at (6,5) {$y=x^2$};
\begin{axis}[xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$}, axis lines=middle, samples=50, grid, thick, domain=-2:2, ymin=-2, xmax=3,
legend style={at={(1.4,.5)}},
legend entries={$y=x^2$}
]
\addplot[blue] {x^2} node[]{$x$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! But I was looking for an actual label, not a legend. [Here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/gnuplot-basics/) is what I'm talking about. I've been trying to use this example in my plot, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @SkeletonBow better?

Comment: Yes! It was so simple, and I was making it more comples than it needed to be. Thank you!